# Improve the code for print json data

Tags: php, json, wordpress, woocommerce, logic

```
function add_price_calculate_tour() {
  global $post;
  $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
  if( $product->is_type( 'tour_booking' ) ):

    $priceAdult = (float) get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_regular_price', true );
    $priceChild = (float) get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 't_children_price', true );

    $tour = json_encode(["priceAdult" => $priceAdult,"priceChild" => $priceChild]);
    wp_add_inline_script( 'twentyseventeen-global', 'var tour = '.$tour.'', 'before' );

  endif;
}
```

I would like to simplify or improve this code, what it does basically is to create an array with a value, and then create a json and print it in the footer.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think the most you can do here is, create the array and convert it to json in the same line.

Comment: Two things maybe (though this is kind of *primarily opinion-based*): Move `$priceAdult` and `$priceChild` into the if block. And you don't need to parse the json with jquery. `json_encode` already produces valid javascript object notation.

Comment: @Yoshi Thank you! I update.

Comment: @Annapurna Thank you! I update.